# Initializing jQuery plugin with noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm attempting work within the constraints of a request and have made some progress bet am still getting locked up. Here's the scenario:

Currently, I'm working with a website that depends on jQuery v1.4.2. Since the only access I'm given on the backend is the ability to inject content into a CMS driven page, I had been sideloading jQuery 1.11 to support for some much needed functionality.

Flash forward to yesterday and I was made aware that the client's dev team has now bundled v1.4 and v1.11 and has noConflicted 1.11 into $$.

```
(function() {
    $$ = $.noConflict( true );  // Move jQuery 1.11.0 into $$ and restore $ to jQuery 1.4.2
})();

// Use the following self-invoking anonymous function 
// when you need to run code that depends on $ = jQuery 1.11
// Otherwise, you can access jquery 1.11 with $$
//  (function( $ ){
// inside here $ is jQuery 1.11
// and jQuery 1.4.2 is out of scope
//  })( $$ );
```

Since my scripts (and the plugin I am attempting to load into the page) are injected in the middle of the page and the jQuery v1.4 and v1.11 are at the bottom of the page, I am loading it this way:

```
(function checkForJquery() {
    if ('$$' in window) {
        (function($) {
            console.log('success');
            $.getScript("myplugin.jquery.js", function() {
                $( ".devices").myplugin({
                    // devices - Array | productID
                    prop1: ["prod3960155", "prod3640151", "prod3640152", "prod5530141"],
                    prop2: "attribute",
                    prop3: "attribute"
                });
            });
        })($$);
    } else {
        console.log('not yet');
        window.setTimeout(checkForJquery, 1000);
    }
})();
```

So the issue I'm having is that if I use:

```
(function( $ ){})( $$ );
```

I get nothing - the plugin never initializes. However, if I use:

```
(function( $ ){})( jQuery );
```

it does work, but then I don't have access to the latest API. Any ideas why one would work and not the other?

For clarity, I'm using the jQuery Plugin Boilerplate and it starts like this:

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) { } )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$$` in the boilerplate too then? `jQuery` belongs to 1.4 ...

Comment: wow, using a 6.5 year old jquery - that website should be in some sort of museum.

Comment: @eisbehr - that seems to be the answer!

Comment: @Jamiec - seriously, I am lucky to have received access to 1.11 as is!

Comment: Great @radiantstatic. I made this an answer then with some more description of the problem. Mark it as success if you like to ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your script won't work is not your call of the plugin, it is the creation.

To explain, the code below only uses the second instance `$$` to search for all elements with the class `.devices` and starts your plugin `myPlugin`. Nothing else.

```
(function($) {
    $(".devices").myplugin();
})($$);
```

But you have registered your plugin only to the old version. This is the reason why it workes, when you use `jQuery` instead of `$$` on the code above.

To use the `$$` jQuery instance in your plugin, you have to set it on creation too. But there you has passed in `jQuery`. And because you used `noConflict`, the name `jQuery` belongs to the old version of jQuery.

To register your plugin to the right instance, you have to change it to `$$` on the creation too.

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){})($$, window, document);
```

To make your plugin working on other installations, you can add `jQuery` as a fallback. This would help if you use the plugin on other sites too and don't want to change it every time.

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){})($$ || jQuery, window, document);
```

Thats it.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. Going off of that, I am having similar issues with using Ken Wheeler's slick slider inside of my `(function($){ $(el).slick();})($$);` but when I go through console and check the extended function on jQuery, $ and $$ - it's not there. Any ideas? https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js

Comment: I think you have to change the line 25 to `factory(window.$$);`.